# How can i replace a string with the required

Tags: c#, string

Hi all i am having my data as follows

```
52201               1                   1         PPD1         111017111017   1111000020000003
```

Here i would like to replace the one with `bold` to `0000002` can any one help me. I used the following but i am unable to replace it

```
if (strBtchno1.StartsWith("5"))
{
    iBtchno = Convert.ToInt16(strBtchno1.Substring(87, 7));
    if (iBtchno > iBatchno)
    {
       iBtchno = iBtchno - 1;                      
       strBtchno1 = strBtchno1.Substring(0,87) + iBtchno.ToString() + strBtchno1.Substring(7,(strBtchno1.Length - 7));
     }                       
  }
```

Comment: You're starting your substring 87 spaces into the string. Shouldn't it be 37, or is the string actually bigger, than what you are showing?

Comment: I would like to replace the text from the character `87 to 94` my maximum length is `94`

Comment: If you mean replace the last 7 digits, [xanatos answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793793/how-can-i-replace-a-string-with-the-required/7793850#7793850) is correct otherwise please explain better.

Comment: If you do the Convert.ToInt16 wont you loose all the leading zeros too?

Comment: @Nicolai formatting issue, I've edited with proper format now.

Comment: The trick is in the formatting of the question :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I edited your edit... Rollbacked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string strBtchno1 = "52201               1                   1         PPD1         111017111017   1111000020000003";
int iBtchno = Convert.ToInt32(strBtchno1.Substring(strBtchno1.Length - 7));
iBtchno++;
strBtchno1 = strBtchno1.Substring(0, strBtchno1.Length - 7) + iBtchno.ToString("d7");
```

7 digits is an `int`, not a `short`!!!

And to format the number back with the padding you can use `iBtchno.ToString("d7")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string newS = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"\*\*[0-9]+\*\*", "0000002");
```

but i dont know if you want regex solution

Comment: What you mean by this will it replace the text as per i needed?

Comment: @if your data contains '*' so yes. you didnt mentioned it

Comment: The `*` were there to try and make the text bold - can't be used inside code block though.